# If boolean is true at any point for longer than X seconds

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building an app using Angular, Ionic, and Firebase.

On the page load I'm setting a boolean `isLoading` to `true`, and as data loads within the app the bool gets set to `false`. This has been pretty reliable, but sometimes, if the internet is slow/fails, the `isLoading` never gets set to `false`, or rather, the function that is supposed to be completed, doesn't.

So my question is, can I have some sort of subscription or "check" to see if `isLoading` is `true` for longer than 3 seconds at any point while the app is active?

The code is pretty simple as I have it so far:

Defining the `isLoading` bool:

```
isLoading: boolean = true;
```

Calling the firebase database:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUser();
});

loadUser() {
  this.database.database.ref('/users/'+this.user.uid).once('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
  });
});
```

Any ideas how I would re-call `loadUser()` if `isLoading` is `true` at any point for more than 3 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want a combination of checking for error conditions and setInterval. This way you can do something periodically while waiting, and you can handle errors from firebase

```
loadUser() {
  let interval = setInterval(() => { 
    if (this.isLoading) {
      //You are still waiting
    }
  }, 3000)
  this.database.database.ref('/users/'+this.user.uid).once('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      clearInterval(interval);
  },
  (error) => {
    //Handle error case
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
};
```

I'm not that familiar with firebase, but you may need to do a similar failure callback within your `ref` call, in case the error is there and not with the handling of `once`

Comment: That is basically what I was talking about @JaneDoe?

Comment: Nice answer btw @rfestag, the clearIntervals are definitely something I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AngularFire2` instead. This will give you a better control of your operations on your database as the reads, writes and updates will return either an `AngularFireList` or `AngularFireObject`.

Basically, these will be values of either an Observable type or a Promise type.

If it's a `Promise` type, you can do the retry or set `isLoading` to `false` in the `catch` callback.

If it's an `Observable` type, you can `retry` the `Observable` or set `isLoading` to `false` in the `finally` callback.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // Do a thing after three seconds
}, 3000);
```

Try this to do on the boolean:

```
(isLoading) ? setTimeout(() => { // Do a thing after three seconds }, 3000) : null
```

Comment: I don't think so, as that would only run once and setInterval with an if statement wouldn't actually run after 3 seconds of the bool being true

Comment: ` (isLoading) ? setTimeout(() => {
    // Do a thing after three seconds
}, 3000) : null `

Comment: I like the try catch idea @Siddharth suggested.